# Creating PDF using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, mpdf

I am using PHPExcel to generate PDF files with mPDF  as the rendering engine.
The output is a table.Is there any way I can output a page title to the pdf file?

Thanks for any help

Simmy

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against using PHPExcel for this task, go with [dompdf](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) instead, its much more robust and flexible in terms of styling.

Look into this PHPExcel object:

```
$objPageSetup = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup()
```

It seems to setup some of the object properties and according to this [post](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/401210) , some of them work for PDF

Comment: PHPExcel isn't actually an alternative to domPDF, PHPExcel can be used __with__ domPDF, or with mPDF, or with tcPDF.... it depends what the OP is using PHPExcel for, but its purpose is creating spreadsheets

Comment: But all I want is a page title.I need to export as both excel and pdf,and I would like to use the same  code for pdf with a page title.Is there no way I can do it in phpexcel? I tried merging cells in phpexcel,but gives error while generating pdf.

Comment: user2280352 You will have to read a little more into PHPExcel PHPExcel_Writer_PDF class inside the code, in order to see how to pass a title option to the pdf. I have used both PHPExcel and domPDF as standalone libraries and they both do an excellent job in its own categorie.

Comment: Look into this PHPExcel object: $objPageSetup = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup() , it seems to setup some of the object properties and according to this post: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/401210 , some of them work for PDF.